# Man pages for alloc_chrdev_region(), register_chrdev() etc system calls

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gnu

I need to know where can I find the man pages for the system calls/routines related to device drivers:

> register_chrdev()
>
> alloc_chrdev_region()

...etc.
I searched in the below links and found definitions:

[Polarhome](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=alloc_chrdev_region&tf=2&of=Oracle&sf=9)

[Unix](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/9/ALLOC_CHRDEV_REGION/)

What I need: There are no header file(s) details where the given call's prototypes present, return types, error conditions etc. and explanations as given in those of man pages in GNU/Linux!

It makes me think: Are they really system calls or something else specifically called!
If they are system calls, why aren't there any man pages in Linux like we do as `man open`,
`man close`,
`man socket`
etc.

Comment: Those functions are not system calls, cannot be used in user space applications. They are part of the linux kernel and these functions form the core of a character device driver. The functions definitions are available at http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2535 and https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.0/ident/alloc_chrdev_region

Comment: Thanks! But one has to be familiar with this link: [http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2535]. Even google search doesn't show this in first few pages!

Comment: If you want a good description of these functions, check [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition By Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, Greg Kroah-Hartman](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/index.html), chapter 3 (char drivers). You can explore their internals and usage further in the linux kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t find the man pages for them. They are the built-in functions that are defined in the `/include/linux/fs.h` file. If you go through them, you can find their definitions.